Linking Agent A arrival at a state as a trigger for Agent B to change from State1 to State 2
Im building a model following the template of the Supply Chain phase 3 model. In my model I want the actor called Firms to go from State1 to State2 based on the agent called IBunits arriving at the state AtFirm. I cant use the same code based on the event as this is based on a distribution and not on a condition (the IBunit arriving at the AtFirm state). Any ideas of how to do this?
This is the tutorial Im following: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/gis/index.html


I tried using the same function by creating extra agents (OrderLink in my case, ProductOrder in the case of the tutorial) but the event that triggers the new orders (in the tutorial) is linked to a distribution:
  // create new Order object and fill its parameters
    OrderLink order = new OrderLink(uniform_discr(5, 20), this); 

    // find available unit is in state "AtUni"
   IBunit iBunit = getNearestAgent( filter(main.iBunits, t -> t.inState(IBunit.AtUni)));

    // if you found a truck
   if (iBunit != null) {
    // assign this order to found truck
    iBunit.order = order;
    // tell the truck to trigger its statechart
    send(order, iBunit);
    }


You need to understand this: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to . Share your agent hierarchy and we can getyou specific code, else try to understand this help page and how to traverse your model hierarchy (i.e. send any message from any agent to any other)

Thank you Benjamin, its a  simple model: 4 agents (Firms and Univs are real agents, and OrderLink is an agent type and IBunits are units modelled as agents as Trucks are in the SC Template. Firms have a event that triggers the creation of an order for the IBunits to go from the distribution (Univs) to the Firms (using discrt_dist).  I would need to create an event but instead of a distribution to be triggered by the IBunit arriving at a state for the Firm to go from State1 to State 2 in its own statechart. I cant add images in the comments unfortunately. Thanks
